# WP Nanoplex 1.0.3 malfunction

Tags: themes, css

I have installed the Nanoplex 1.0.3 theme for Wordpress and the orange content bars begin waaaay off the left side of the page, rendering them usless.

They aren't starting at the left margin and bleeding off right as they do in the theme page.  Please help.

I love this theme.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try version 1.0.5 as it fixes a lot of bugs.
What web browser are you using? Nanoplex doesn't work on IE 6/7.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues, using Firefox. Nanoplex doesn't work in IE8 either. 
Website is still under construction and it looks fantastic, except for this issue (so far).